# brew installation for zsh?

Tags: zsh, homebrew

Hi I just followed the thoughtbot laptop setup for my Mac Mini Server running OSX Lion
 Server. I'm not sure that everything is installed correctly. Please advise.

I don't have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` but i do have a `~/.profile`

But here are contents for `.zshrc` since I use `.zsh`.

```
   1 # load our own completion functions
   2 fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)
   3 
   4 # completion
   5 autoload -U compinit
   6 compinit
   7 
   8 # automatically enter directories without cd
   9 setopt auto_cd
  10 
  11 # use vim as an editor
  12 export EDITOR=vim
  13 
  14 # aliases
  15 if [ -e "$HOME/.aliases" ]; then
  16   source "$HOME/.aliases"
  17 fi
  18 
  19 # vi mode
  20 bindkey -v
  21 bindkey "^F" vi-cmd-mode
  22 bindkey jj vi-cmd-mode
  23 
  24 # use incremental search
  25 bindkey "^R" history-incremental-search-backward
  26 
  27 # add some readline keys back
  28 bindkey "^A" beginning-of-line
  29 bindkey "^E" end-of-line
  30 
  31 # handy keybindings
  32 bindkey "^P" history-search-backward
  33 bindkey "^Y" accept-and-hold
  34 bindkey "^N" insert-last-word
  35 bindkey -s "^T" "^[Isudo ^[A" # "t" for "toughguy"
  36 
  37 # expand functions in the prompt
  38 setopt prompt_subst
  39 
  40 # prompt
  41 export PS1='[${SSH_CONNECTION+"%n@%m:"}%~] '
  42 
  43 # ignore duplicate history entries
  44 setopt histignoredups
  45 
  46 # keep TONS of history
  47 export HISTSIZE=4096
  48 
  49 # look for ey config in project dirs
  50 export EYRC=./.eyrc
  51 
  52 # automatically pushd
  53 setopt auto_pushd
  54 export dirstacksize=5
  55 
  56 # awesome cd movements from zshkit
  57 setopt AUTOCD
  58 setopt AUTOPUSHD PUSHDMINUS PUSHDSILENT PUSHDTOHOME
  59 setopt cdablevars
  60 
  61 # Try to correct command line spelling
  62 setopt CORRECT CORRECT_ALL
  63 
  64 # Enable extended globbing
  65 setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
  66 
  67 # RVM
  68 [[ -s '/Users/pma/.rvm/scripts/rvm' ]] && source '/Users/pma/.rvm/scripts/rvm'
```

Brew complains with brew doctor

```
[~] brew doctor
/usr/bin is in your PATH before Homebrew's bin. This means that system-
provided programs will be used before Homebrew-provided ones. This is an
issue if you install, for instance, Python.

Consider editing your .bashrc to put:
  /usr/local/bin
ahead of /usr/bin in your $PATH.
```

zsh:

```
[~] zsh --version
zsh --version
zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)
```

So how can I ensure brew is installed correctly and remove the errors from brew doctor?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: [~] echo $PATH
/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/pma/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/pma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/pma/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try setting this line in your `.zshrc`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 142):

This worked for me on macOS **ARM** (Apple M1):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

and then:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I confirm this works on M1 Mac. Adding the same line to `.zprofile` *as suggested by the brew install* did *not* work.

Comment: @SeanDeNigris Interestingly, `.zprofile` did work for me!

Comment: `echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: @SeanDeNigris `.zprofile` instead of `.zshrc` also worked for me !

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 22):

Not sure if this is late but you can simply run this to add Homebrew to your `PATH`:

```
eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

Comment: I added this line to my `~/.zshrc` and now I can run `brew` every time.

Answer (score 11):

I use **ohmyzsh**. Go to the directory

```
cd /usr/local/bin
brew doctor
```

You will notice it shows warnings like:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
autoconf
automake
gdbm
gnupg
libgpg-error
libksba
libtool
libyaml
mongodb
node
pcre
pkg-config
zsh
```

You will have to run a command here:

```
brew link zsh
```

And that link it for me.

Comment: THANK YOU for posting, you helped me out a lot! I used osx terminal forever then installed brew and all my packages weren't working. I had to run `brew doctor` to fix.

Comment: `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew doctor` in case brew command is not defined and you installed there

Answer (score 9):

Following @Sajjad's answer did help but I had to run that command every time I started a new terminal which was

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

I don't know much unix but what's going on here I believe is that we are appening
`export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"` part to our `.zshrc` file which at the root of our file structure at the end of the file.

So, I ran

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

and added

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

at the end and it worked for all terminals from then on.

I am on the M1 if that is relevant

Comment: Worked for me on Macbook Pro M2

Answer (score 8):

Open the ~/.zshrc file first line in file says

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

just comment out second line it will start working :)

Answer (score 5):

After installing Homebrew by the below command

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Run

```
echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/atubasi/.zprofile
```

Then run

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

This will evaluate if your setup for Homebrew is working fine or not. You can run `brew help` to ensure that brew is defined in your zsh profile.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason none of the solutions here worked for me until I had to put *both* of the following two lines into my .zshrc file

`export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"`

`export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:$PATH"`

Then restart your zsh shell and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For permanent fix just execute the below command:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```